# The Theorem of Bolzano? explanation required

Tags: calculus

I'm currently writing on an internal assessment in the IB about speeding tickets using the mean value theorem and I read this online project about it. Besides the point at the end it mentions the theorem of Bolzano (intermediate value theorem). I'm not exactly sure how it is used in the speeding ticket situation and I would love it if I could get some help. Below you can find the link to it. Thanks in advance if I don't answer back! :)

Link: http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~stroyan/CTLC3rdEd/ProjectsOldCD/estroyan/cd/20/

Apologies for tagging calculus, I know it's based on theorem and I don't have 1000 reputation to pick something else.